# Laravel 5 app::error

Tags: php, laravel-4, error-handling, laravel-5

I'm upgrading another Laravel 4 to 5 instance. There is a file "ExceptionServiceProvider" in the Exceptions now. With following code:

```
<?

namespace KeepIt\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ExceptionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        \App::error(function(AjaxException $exception)
        {
            $response = array(
                'state'     => false,
                'message'   => $exception->getErrorMessage(),
                'errors'    => $exception->getErrors(),
                'type'      => $exception->getType()
            );

            return \Response::json($response);
        });
    }
}
```

I know App::error isn't working anymore in L5, but I don't get it to rewrite this code. It's not a 404 it's a 500 error throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it... I just had to put the code to the new Exceptions/Handler.php where the render function is.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
            if($e instanceof AjaxException){
        $response = array(
            'state'     => false,
            'message'   => $e->getErrorMessage(),
            'errors'    => $e->getErrors(),
            'type'      => $e->getType()
        );
        return \Response::json($response);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$status = 500 //Could be whatever you need
Response::json(['myMsg' => 'FooBar'], $status)
```

or

```
abort(404);
```

Comment: Don't get it... in laravel 5 App::error dosn't work anymore so I have to rewrite it if the app throws an 500 and response with json like it shows in the code.